# Set image as background of svg circle element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js, svg-filters

I want to add an image inside every center bubble node. I am able to add an image but it is acting like hidden pattern for background and wherever bubble moves it exposes the visible part of the hidden pattern which is in the background. Actually my aim is to achieve something which is in this (http://jsfiddle.net/LsMZp/2/) fiddle. Here is my fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/m2hLvr4r/1/). I have written the same code as in the previous fiddle to add an image inside a circle but I could not able to achieve this and I am trying it from previous one day. Please some one help me out.

Comment: It'd be much easier to work on smaller piece of code.

Comment: I have changed the patternUnits but it is slowing down the animation spped.